# RoR: Delegating email with Devise and login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two tables, a Users table and a table called School_Users. The School_Users table handles role and various other fields for users including email.

I have delegated email to this model:

user.rb

```
delegate :email, to: :school_user
```

And it appears to work, I am using active admin and tested it there.

But when I go to sign in in the application I get this error:

```
User#email delegated to school_user.email, but school_user is nil: #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil>
```

I guess this is just the view, here is my form with email field:

/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

              <p class="loginLogo"><%= image_tag "logo.png", class: "text-center" %></p>
                <%= f.label :email, :class => "text-center font16" %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> 
                <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "insdat", :placeholder => "Email Address", autofocus: true %>
              <%= f.label :password, :class => "text-center font16" %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span><%= f.password_field :password, :class => "insdat" , :placeholder => "Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
                <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Log in", :class => "expanded button logbtn" %> 
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">

<% end %>
```

How would I get the form to load? I take it I have to define the field toward school_user or find a path??

Thanks. Happy to post more code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the instance of `User` being used has a `nil` value for the `school_user`.

You can fix that by allowing `nil`s with:

```
delegate :email, to: :school_user, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, just wondering does this have any drawbacks in your opinion? Thanks. P.S i'm using Devise.